# UIToolbar height on device rotation

Tags: iphone, ios, uitoolbar

From the iOS Human Interface Guidelines, [iOS UI Element Usage Guidelines](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/mobilehig/UIElementGuidelines/UIElementGuidelines.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006556-CH13-SW10)

> **On iPhone, take into account the
>   automatic change in toolbar height
>   that occurs on device rotation**. In
>   particular, make sure your custom
>   toolbar icons fit well in the thinner
>   bar that appears in landscape
>   orientation. Don’t specify the height
>   of a toolbar programmatically.

I can see the height changing from 44 points to 32 points in *Mail*, *Twitter for iPhone* and *Dropbox* for example, but when I add a toolbar (with Interface Builder) and have my UIViewController subclass to automatically rotate (`shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:` returns YES), the toolbar does not automatically change its height on device rotation.

The [UIToolbar Class Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIToolbar_Class/Reference/Reference.html) does not mention this automatic change of height, so am I supposed to change it programmatically even though the HIG says *Don’t specify the height of a toolbar programmatically*?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

As noted by **yonel** and **George** in the comments from **7KV7** answer, changing the autoresizing mask does not work as intended on iOS 5.

I found another solution by using the [-[UIView sizeThatFits:]](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/uiview_class/uiview/uiview.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIView/sizeThatFits%3a) method. Here is how I did it:

```
- (void) layoutForInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    // Adjust the toolbar height depending on the screen orientation
    CGSize toolbarSize = [self.toolbar sizeThatFits:self.view.bounds.size];
    self.toolbar.frame = (CGRect){CGPointMake(0.f, CGRectGetHeight(self.view.bounds) - toolbarSize.height), toolbarSize};
    self.webView.frame = (CGRect){CGPointZero, CGSizeMake(CGRectGetWidth(self.view.bounds), CGRectGetMinY(self.toolbar.frame))};
}
```

Then I call this `layoutForInterfaceOrientation:` method in my view controller `viewWillAppear:` and `willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation:duration:` methods.

The height is nonetheless changed programmatically but at least the value is not hardcoded.

Answer (score 19):

Did you check the auto-resizing property of the toolbar?

Comment: That's it, you have to do `toolbar.autoresizingMask = toolbar.autoresizingMask | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;` programmatically as Interface Builder doesn't allow you to change the flexible height!

Comment: don't you have a side effect with iOS5.0 with this solution ? It works ok but the icons in the toolbar always have the landscape (=smaller) size, even in portrait :/

Comment: I second yonel - the icons retain the small size in both orientation. Also, once rotated, it doesn't position it properly - there's an extra uncovered pixel at the bottom of the screen. I wonder if there's a god reason for the resizing mask to be disabled in IB...

Comment: I think you are seeing that pixel issue and icon size issue for two reasons. First, the pixel issue is because your struts are not set properly for your views above/below the toolbar. Second, the icon sizing issue is probably because you are adjusting the autoresizingMask in the viewDidLoad method. Try doing this in the viewWillAppear method. Doing these makes it work as expected for me in iOS 6.

Comment: @0xced you can find autoresizing masks in Interface Builder. Just go to the 'Size' tab and you'll see the Autosizing box on the left

Answer (score 12):

This behavior is a lot simpler to achieve with auto layout. I've only tested in iOS8 but the following code works for me with the desired animation on orientation change:

```
public override func viewWillLayoutSubviews() {
    super.viewWillLayoutSubviews()
    toolbar.invalidateIntrinsicContentSize()
}
```

Comment: Works great on iOS 9.

Comment: This almost worked, I had to add toolbar.sizeToFit() after the invalidateIntrinsicContentSize();

Answer (score 2):

If you use a ViewController inside a NavigationController, you can use the NavigationController’s toolbar instead of creating your own, and let it handle the resizing. This is what the ViewController's `toolbarItems` property is for, actually.

Comment: I'm aware of this solution, but when you push view controller B onto view controller A, if A doesn't want a toolbar and B wants a toolbar, you can't get a nice *push* horizontal animation. The toolbar animation is vertical while the push transition animation is horizontal so it looks awkward in my opinion. Not animating the toolbar is even worse.