# Toolbar height resets to 44px in landscape after presenting view controller

Tags: iphone, ios, toolbar, landscape

I'm using the method posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12111810/61478) to adjust the size of my toolbar when rotating the device. This works well and it shows the appropriate size including icon size etc.

However, when I present a view controller with `[self presentViewController:theViewController animated:YES completion:nil];`, the toolbar height gets set back to 44px instead of 32. It's easy to see that the size increase already happens when presenting the view controller as it's already taller during the animation. It also remains tall after dismissing the view controller. The app targets iOS 6. Just in case that might be related.

Is there a way to keep the smaller size in landscape?

Answer (score 0):

Reduce your target developement to lower than iOS 6 and it will work. Just a wild guess.:)

Comment: Changing the deployment target to 5.1 resulted in the same effect, no improvement. Is that what you meant?